# Groovy list in a map not showing a loop count properly

Tags: list, groovy, hashmap

I have this code in Groovy;

```
def execution = []
def executor =[:]
for(loopcount=1;loopcount<4;loopcount++){
    executor.executor = 'jmeter'
    executor.scenario = 'scenario' + loopcount
    println executor.scenario
    executor.concurrency = 2
    execution.add(executor)
}
execution.each{
    println executor.scenario
}
```

It is a list of three maps, all the same apart from the scenario suffix increments. I am expecting;

```
scenario1
scenario2
scenario3
scenario1
scenario2
scenario3
```

But I get;

```
scenario1
scenario2
scenario3
scenario3
scenario3
scenario3
```

It's definitely adding three different maps in the list because the .each command is returning three values. And they're definitely different values in executor.scenario because the println in the loop is giving the correct '1, 2, 3' count. But why don't they stay as different values in the list?

I've also tried execution.push(executor) but that gives the same results. For context, this yaml is what I'm aiming for eventually;

```
---
execution:
- executor: "jmeter"
  scenario: "scenario1"
  concurrency: 2
- executor: "jmeter"
  scenario: "scenario2"
  concurrency: 2
- executor: "jmeter"
  scenario: "scenario3"
  concurrency: 2
```

And apart from the scenario count the rest of it works fine.

Comment: Is there a concept of 'byval' and 'byref' here? If so, do I need to do something to execution.add(executor) to make it take the values rather than references?

Comment: just move `def executor =[:]` declaration inside `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem:

```
def execution = []
def executor =[:]
for(loopcount=1;loopcount<4;loopcount++){
    execution.add(executor) // <<-- this line adds the same variable to the list 4 times
}
```

to fix this - declare `executor` inside the `for` loop

```
def execution = []
for(loopcount=1;loopcount<4;loopcount++){
    def executor =[:]       // <<-- creates a new object in a loop
    execution.add(executor) // <<-- adds new object to a list
}
```

probably to make it more clear, let me specify what `[]` and `[:]` means:

```
def execution = new ArrayList()
for(loopcount=1;loopcount<4;loopcount++){
    def executor = new LinkedHashMap()
    execution.add(executor)
}
```

however you could declare the variable before the loop but you have to assign a new object into it inside loop

```
def execution = []
def executor
for(loopcount=1;loopcount<4;loopcount++){
    executor = [:]
    execution.add(executor)times
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple fix, thanks! I didn't think I was going to be able to do another declare in a loop, I thought it was just going to tell me to go away on the second loop. I was actually looking for a way of 'deleting' the executor so I could reuse it, but of course Java (and by extension Groovy) doesn't have anything to drop an object.